# Include ctags files recursively from a directory

Tags: vim, ctags

I am using Ctags with Vim successfully. Currently, my setting for tags is as below:

```
set tags=./tags;/
```

I have a directory `~/.ctags` which contains files such as: `~/.ctags/rails`, `~/.ctags/laravel` etc. which are basically ctags generated for specific projects which I might need from some other project of mine.

Is there a way, I can tell Vim to include all these files for ctags-purposes?
something like:

```
set tags+=~/.ctags/*
```

Can someone also explain to me the pros and cons of using this approach v/s generating all my ctags (from ruby, php, python, etc. projects) in a single file??

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help 'tags'` explains:

> The filename itself cannot contain wildcards, it is used as-is.

So you either need to explicitly add all tags on startup:

```
for tagfile in split(glob('~/.ctags/*'), "\n")
    let &tags .= ',' . tagfile
endfor
```

or change your tag generation to put identically named files in subdirectories. Then you can use the `*` wildcard to include them all:

```
set tags+=~/.ctags/*/tags
```

I haven't used tags that much, but I think it is a good practice to separate them. After all, Vim does support multiple tag file locations.